# snort spp_sfPortscan Preprocessor Customization

Tags: sniffer, detection, snort, c

I am working in snort 2.9.8.0. I want to modify the snort code for Portscanning Detection,i.e spp_sfPortscan.c and its related code to build a customized portScan detector.

Ex:suppose A is scanning 10 ports of B which are highly critical ,like 139,445,etc. And C is scanning 20 non-critical ports of D . Now,i want to calculate an average score for each scanning host,which would be [Weight(critical ports)*no.of critical ports + Weight(non-critical ports)*no.of non-critical ports]/Total no.of ports scanned.

If the score for a host exceeds a threshold then only i generate an alert for that host,else not.

Anyone please suggest me,as to where should i write code for calculating(as in,where in spp_sfPortscan.c or which functions should be hooked).

I am certain that people must have gone way more far than this and it would be greatly apprieciating to help @Newbies by sharing some.

Thanks and Regards Cyrus

Comment: A snort support forum is probably a better place to ask this.